# View reviews and ratings in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am logging on App Store Connect after a long time and I see that they have changed the layout and stuff for the website.

Where can I view the reviews and ratings, that people have posted for my app on App Store Connect?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### App Store Connect (responsive redesign, June 2020)

1. Open **Apps** and select the app.
2. Choose **App Store** from the top.
3. Select **Ratings and Reviews** from the sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2021, it has moved. Select your Apps > Your App > Ratings and Reviews in the left panel menu.

[image]